# How to fix array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in PHP?

Tags: php

### Details

- I have 6 continents = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
- I want to loop through them and make a nice `nav-menu` out of them.

### Here is what I have tried

```
   <nav id="nav">
    <ul class="container">

        <?php foreach(array_unique(array_values($continent)) as $continent_id){

            if($continent_id == 1 ) $continent = "Europe" ;  
            elseif ($continent_id == 2 ) $continent = "Asia" ;  
            elseif ($continent_id == 3 ) $continent = "North America" ;  
            elseif ($continent_id == 4 ) $continent = "Oceania" ;  
            elseif ($continent_id == 5 ) $continent = "South America" ;  
            else  $continent == "Africa" ; 

            ?> 

            <!-- HTML go here  -->

            <li><a href="#<?php echo $continent ; ?>"><?php echo $continent ; ?> </a></li>


            <?php } ?>

        </ul>
    </nav>
```

### Here is what I get

Error message say : array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given !

Can someone tell me what I missed ?

Comment: Obviously `$continent` is a string, not an array. `var_dump($continent)` will show you that. Since you don't show **HOW** you create `$continent`, we can't help you.

Comment: if you     var_dump($continent) you will know - it isn't array

Comment: The solution is to make sure that `$continent` is an array.... and while it shouldn't cause a problem, re-assigning `$continent` inside your loop is certainly going to confuse

Comment: Can you show us exactly how you're using the numbered array and where they're coming from?

Comment: You're doing `<?php echo $continent ; ?>`, `$continent` is a string.

Comment: @RocketHazmat : So why can't I do that ?

Comment: @evoque2015: `array_values` works on arrays.  `echo` works on strings.

Comment: You are re declare  `$continent` with a string!

Comment: TBH, I'm not entirely sure how your code works, in conjunction with 1,2,3,4,5,6. What did (kind of) worked for me was `$continent = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);` However, it did echo an additional "South America" in the list menu, and showing all of the continents in the list, whether that is the intended result.

Comment: I think I have a naming conflict with my array name as `continent`. I fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it. Yay ! Thank you everyone for your comments. :D. You guys are awesome.

### Here is my working code

```
<!-- Nav -->
<nav id="nav">
    <ul class="container">

        <?php 

        foreach(array_unique(array_values($continent)) as $continent_id){


            if($continent_id == 1 ) $continent_name = "Europe" ;  
            elseif ($continent_id == 2 ) $continent_name = "Asia" ;  
            elseif ($continent_id == 3 ) $continent_name = "North America" ;  
            elseif ($continent_id == 4 ) $continent_name = "Oceania" ;  
            elseif ($continent_id == 5 ) $continent_name = "South America" ;  
            else  $continent_name == "Africa" ;  

            ?>

            <li><a href="#<?php echo $continent_name ?>"><?php echo $continent_name ?> </a></li>

            <?php }?>


        </ul>
    </nav>
```

### Here is the result

[image]

Comment: Great and you're welcome. Yet what [I mentioned earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827312/how-to-fix-array-values-expects-parameter-1-to-be-array-string-given-in-php#comment44060911_27827312) in my using `$continent = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);` placed just before `foreach(array_unique(array_values($continent)) as $continent_id){` produced the same result. How are you iterating through the 1-6 array?

Answer (score 0):

```
$continent = "Europe"
```

in first loop you change array into string - so IMHO you should change $continent to something else ;-)